# BigQuery parse_datetime issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I need to convert string into date in GCP BigQuery .
String format is "29-NOV-15 12.00.00.000000000 AM"

While I am suing SELECT parse_datetime('%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S.%E*S %P', pg) , pg FROM abc

It's throwing me error saying

Failed to parse input string "29-NOV-15 12.00.00.000000000 AM".

Can someone pls look into this and point me the error.

Answer (score 1):

use below instead

```
SELECT parse_datetime('%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%E*S %p', pg) , pg 
FROM abc
```

with output (for sample string in your question)

[image]